# Java prepared statement without result set?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement, resultset

I'm using a Java prepared statement to execute a stored procedure in PostgreSQL database. Like this:

```
    String sql = "select testFkt(?,?,?,?,?)";
    try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, a
        preparedStatement.setInt(2, b);
        preparedStatement.setInt(3, c);
        preparedStatement.setByte(4, d);
        preparedStatement.setString(5, "test");
        try (ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {

        }
    }
```

The stored procedures return a result but I'm not interested in the result.

Do I still have to use the `ResultSet` (and try-with) or can I just use `preparedStatement.executeQuery()`?

My fear is that there is a stream or something like that opened because the stored procedures returns a result and that this stream is not closed if I'm not using a `ResultSet`.

Comment: Note that sometimes (depending on database and specifics of the stored procedure), you actually **need** to read the **entire** result set for the stored procedure to actually do all of its work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, then you could use [`PreparedStatmenet.execute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute%28%29) instead (that way you won't get the `ResultSet`).

That is, change this

```
try (ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
}
```

to

```
preparedStatement.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object that generated it is closed. So you can just close the statement to close the ResultSet Stream.

Visit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html for more details

Although if your requirement is to execute a stored procedure you can use JDBC **Callable Statement API**

Visit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html for more details

Sample below:

```
Connection dbConnection = null;         
CallableStatement callableStatement = null;  
String storedProc = "{call storedProc (?,?)}";
    try{
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(storedProc); 
        callableStatement.setInt(1, 1);  
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.DATE); 
        callableStatement.executeUpdate();                                     
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        //handle exception
    } finally {             
       if (callableStatement != null) {         
            callableStatement.close();          
       }            
       if (dbConnection != null) {  
            dbConnection.close();           
       }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you still want the resultset to be closed.